# How to make find_theorems more specific

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to find a theorem in Isabelle (2021) to the following effect:

```
lemma "A ⟹ B ⟹ A ∧ B"
```

So far, I have tried to use the following pattern:

```
find_theorems "_ ⟹ _ ⟹ _ ∧ _"
```

but it obviously returns a lot of results, as the pattern is too abstract. The various placeholders `_` can represent very different things from one another.

I was wondering if there is any way to be more specific in the search, to express that some of the placeholders are the same. For example, can the following hypothetical example be achieved in Isabelle's search facilities?

```
find_theorems "_1 ⟹ _2 ⟹ _1 ∧ _2"
```

(indicating that all `_1`s are the same variable, all the `_2`s are the same etc.)

Comment: You can use "?A" for patterns (exactly like in `is`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, `find_theorems` also take patterns as arguments similar to `is`. So anything of the form '?' followed by a string (and optionally a number [1]) can be used.

```
find_theorems "?A \<Longrightarrow> ?B \<Longrightarrow> ?A \<and> ?B"
(*
  "?A ⟹ ?B ⟹ ?A ∧ ?B"

found 1 theorem(s):
•  HOL.conjI: ?P ⟹ ?Q ⟹ ?P ∧ ?Q
*)
```

[1] with the usual caveat that "?A0" and "?A" refer to the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks. What I got for the same command is:   found 1 theorem(s):
  HOL.conjI: ?P ∧ ?Q ⟹ ?P ∧ ?Q  . (with Isabelle 2021). Do you happen to know why the premise is written as a conjunction in the search result?

Comment: That is very odd. The symbol "∧" and "⟹" are completely different… Are you using the default font? Does `thm conjI` also produce the wrong theorem?

Comment: yes, `thm conjI` also produced `?P ∧ ?Q ⟹ ?P ∧ ?Q`. I thought there was some automatic conversion going on. The Isabelle 2021 is expanded from the downloaded binary on Ubuntu.

Comment: @tinlyx What theories are loaded? Can your write down a complete (minimal) theory file that gives the result you mention?